# Can macOS Shortcuts be opened in browsers other than Safari, such as Google Chrome?

Tags: icloud, safari, google-chrome, shortcuts-app

I've noticed that when using other browsers, such as Google Chrome, links to custom macOS Shortcuts shared on iCloud don't show up as they do in Safari:
[image: Safari Shortcut Shared]

Is there any method for making user Shortcuts openable in browsers other than Safari in macOS?

Comment: How do you even manage to open them in Safari?

Comment: Just go to an online resource, this site, for example, seems to offer some: https://shortcutsgallery.com/. When I went to one there and it took me to the iCloud URL then it simply asks if I want to open it in Shortcuts.app.

Comment: Oh, yes, I was able to do that too. I must've misunderstood: I thought you could see those shortcuts directly in-browser (in-Safari). Also, what do you mean by "they don't show up as they do in Safari"? Is the link unresponsive (doesn't open Shortcuts.app)?

Comment: When using Chrome it doesn't show the option to open it, example of a Shortcuts share in Chrome: https://share.getcloudapp.com/eDuEANmr

Answer (score 0):

The [Actions app](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1586435171) provides a “Open URLs with App” action to open a URL in a specific browser.

*Disclosure: I'm the author.*

Comment: Hmm, interesting, but does it allow Shortcuts to be opened outside of Safari as per the original question?